# Does this rule eventually lead to $0^n1^n$

Tags: proof-writing, binary

If you're given a binary string of the form $a_1a_2\ldots a_n \overline {a_1a_2\ldots a_n}$, will the following rule applied a finite number eventually lead to the string $0^n1^n$ where exponentiation means concatenation $n$ times. Rule:

1) Swap the bits in positions $a_n$ and $\overline{a_n}$ (the indices remain constant, i.e. the $n^{th}$ bit and the $2n^{th}$ bit)

2) Rotate the longest suffix of zeros to the beginning of the string.

Example on the string $000110111001$, applying first step we get $000111111000$ and then applying the second step we rotate the last 3 zeros and get $000000111111$.

I know that it makes intuitive sense that eventually you get to the $0^n1^n$, because you're kind of ironing out the zeros that are stuck between ones. But how would you formally prove that this always happens? Would it be some kind of inductive proof or a proof by contradiction?

Comment: What do you do if you're at a string like $00101110$?

Comment: @vrugtehagel Writing $a_1a_2\ldots a_n \overline {a_1a_2\ldots a_n}$ suggests that the second half is the complement of the first half, so your string isn't a valid starting point.

Comment: Excuse me. It was unclear to me that $\overline{a_i}=1-a_i$.

Comment: This may be stupid but please explain step 1. If you swap the bits being the negated values of each other then 000110.111001 would become 111001.000110 - seems I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that after the second step, the amount of $0$'s that our string is starting with has increased by at least $1$. Thus, we're done after at least $n$ steps, since then our string starts with at least $n$ zeroes. And since we have exactly $n$ zeroes, we have the string $0^n1^n$.

Comment: Is there any way to prove that this rule gives the lexicographically smallest string closed under rotation if you start with a lexicographically smallest string? So like if you start with $00101101$ that is the lexicographically smallest string closed under rotation. If you try any other rotation it will be bigger.  Like a rotation is just moving a suffix to the beginning or a prefix to the end.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the term "lexicographically smallest string". I do want to note however that if this is a *different* question, then the question should be asked in a different post.

Comment: It is a different question, I will ask it in a different post.